# How to chart and metrices based on SQL Database data in azure Monitor

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I have to create chart and metrices in Azure Monitor overview dashboard based on Azure SQL database data. How can we do that? I don't want to show database performance. I want to display database data in dashboard.

Comment: *I want to display database data in dashboard* afaik that is not possible. Use tooling like Power BI for creating dashboards showing actual data. In general, use azure monitor dashboards to show data regarding the resource, it is not meant to display data regarding the content of the resource (unless it is a log analytics workspace or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Monitor helps you maximize the availability and performance of
> your applications and services like CPU performance, memory usage,
> storage usage, etc. It can't be used to visualize the stored data in
> Azure SQL database or any other service.

To visualize the data, you should either use tools like **Azure Data Explorer** or **Power BI**.

Please check [Visualize data with Azure Data Explorer dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/azure-data-explorer-dashboards).